# Safe removal of vertexes in ArangoDB (using _ids)?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm creating some removal queries for vertices and edges in ArangoDB using AQL and I  assumed there would be a "safe" way to delete vertices that would also remove associated edges. But I can't find any in the documentation or anywhere else. Is the following the best way to do a safe delete?

```
FOR e IN GRAPH_EDGES('EdgeClass',docId,{direction:'any',maxDepth:1, includeData:false})
    REMOVE e._key FROM EdgeClass
```

combined with

```
REMOVE docKey IN DocumentClass
```

Also, is there a way to remove vertices (or edges) using `_id`s or is it necessary to use `_key`s? I couldn't get the former to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting vertices is currently not handled via AQL. [The graph management interface offers vertex deletion functionality](https://docs.arangodb.com/GeneralGraphs/Management.html#remove-a-vertex).

The [programming language specific driver](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#graphvertexcollectionremove) usually offers wrappers [for the REST interfaces to these methods](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpGharial/Vertices.html#remove-a-vertex).

If you want to design an AQL query that does this for you, you'd i.e. have to know whether a vertex is only used in one graph, and the number of edge collections that could be concerned by this deletion. You would probably want to use the [more modern graph traversals](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html). Lets try to [remove eve from the knows graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html#the-knowsgraph):

```
LET keys = (
  FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY 'persons/eve' GRAPH 'knows_graph' RETURN e._key)
     LET r = (FOR key IN keys REMOVE key IN knows) REMOVE 'eve' IN persons
```

So, we let the [the traversal give us the `_key` of all edges of Eve](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html). We then remove all these edges from the `knows` edge collection. After that we remove Eve herself.

However, you can easily see that you have to craft such a query specific for your situation.

**edit**: one can do this a little more elegant like this:

```
LET keys = (FOR v, e IN 1..1 ANY 'persons/eve' GRAPH 'knows_graph'
            REMOVE e._key IN knows)
  REMOVE 'eve' IN persons
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using arangojs in Node, so I tried this function: https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#graphvertexcollectionremove . However, it still doesn't seem to be deleting neighboring edges. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Simply calling REST interface using curl does delete both the vertex and neighboring edges.

Comment: @ropeladder the behaviour of that function changed in the last minor release to match the expected behaviour. It was previously just using the raw collection API which could result in dangling edges, now it uses the graph collection API. Could you make sure you are using the latest version of arangojs?

Comment: Yep, not using the latest arangojs was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I see in the ArangoDB documentation:

> "Data-modification queries are restricted to modifying data in a single collection per query. That means a data-modification query cannot modify data in multiple collections with a single query."

I wondered if the documentation is out of date, if it is indeed possible to remove documents from multiple collections in a single AQL query?

Comment: Yes, it has been removed meanwhile. The documentation needs to be fixed.

Comment: However, you can't specify multiple delete/update statements for one collection in a query.

Comment: Your edit assigns to `keys` but never uses it for anything.

Comment: meanwhile the gharial API has been rewritten in C++, so the performance penalty of using it has become smaller. As parts of the AQL described above, all whats said there remains true.